# IBM Cloud Functions parameters are undefined

Tags: ibm-cloud-functions

I'm using an IBM Cloud Functions web action but can not access the parameters.

**Parameters:**
[image]

**Code:**

```
function main(params) {

module = params.module;
attribute = params.attribute;

var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: params.uri,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        },
        body: {
            module: module
        },
        json: true
    };

    console.log(options);
    return { message: options };
}
```

**IBM Cloud Functions Output:**

[image]

**Postman Output**

[image]

Comment: How do you invoke action? It seems that you defined it as web action. Have you tried leaving out the quotes in your form?

Comment: I invoke it directly in the browser. Yes, it's a web action. Leaving out the quotes in not possible as I wouldn't be able to save the parameters. I also added the Postman output.

Comment: when your functions returns just params, what is the output?

Comment: it's working now for some reason , after returning params as advised. I didn't change anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotations from the parameter name field, then try it again. it works for me.[Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TEKR.jpg)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You can find more information on how to authenticate IBM parameters on [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dDCIz2bbv0I&t=265s]